# How to get an HTML anchor tag from an external markdown file frontmatter property in Astro?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, markdown, astrojs

I am building a component in Astro, which I want to fill with markdown from an Astro content collection. It all works, but I cannot get the markdown link from the md frontmatter to work as an html anchor tag in the component file.

This is the md frontmatter code:

```
---
[some md properties]
link: '[name](url) '
---

some markdown text
```

I first reference the different contents from the markdown file with template string literals and then try to replace the markdown in the anchor tag with some regex, but it only displays the md string as a working link:

```
import { getCollection } from 'astro:content';
const projects = await getCollection('projects');
console.log(projects);
---

{
  projects.map((project) => (
    <>
      <div id='project_cards' class='bg-secondary rounded-[5px]'>
        <div class='project_card flex-col bg-secondary'>
          <img src={`${project.data.image}`} alt={`${project.data.title}`} />
        </div>
        <div class='project_card_description flex flex-col gap-[60px] p-[60px]'>
          <SectionTitle sec1={`${project.data.title}`} sec2='' />
          <p class='project_description'>{project.body}</p>
          <div class='social_links'>
            <a href={`${project.data.link}`}>{`${project.data.link}`}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  ))
}

<script>
  //md links to html anchor tags
  const md_social_link = `${project.data.link}`;
  // md replacement for anchor tags
  const html_social_link = md_social_link.replace(
    /\[([^\[]+)\](\(([^)]*))\)/gim,
    '<a href="$3" target?"_blank">$1</a>'
    /**
     * '<a href="$3">$1</a>': This is the replacement string for the matched pattern. It's HTML code that will be used to replace the Markdown-style link.
     *
     * <a href="$3">$1</a>: This is an anchor tag (<a>). $3 and $1 are placeholders that refer to the capturing groups in the regex pattern:
     * $3: This refers to the URL captured by the second capturing group (\(([^)]*))\)).
     * $1: This refers to the link text captured by the first capturing group ([^\[]+).s
     **/
  );

  //append to div ".social_links"
  console.log(html_social_link);
  let div_social_links = document.querySelector('.social_links');
  // Check if div_social_links is not null before using it
  if (div_social_links) {
    div_social_links.innerHTML = html_social_link;
  } else {
    // Handle the case where .social_links is not found
    console.error('Error: .social_links element not found.');
  }
</script>
```

In the script part, I get the following error when hovering on the template string: `Cannot find name "project"`. I suppose that there must be a problem with correctly referencing the frontmatter property, but I don't know how I can fix it to work with a markdown link.
How can I achieve to effectively split the markdown link so that I can use it for the anchor tag? Is this even possible?

Comment: it is easy to see your errror manifests from `${project.data.link}`;` here methinks.  Are you thinking you reference `const projects = await getCollection('projects');`? as you do NOT.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Yes, that is my goal. I want to access the link property of the md frontmatter in the same way as the other properties in the Astro code above. The Astro code is working so far, only the reference in the `<script>` tag does not work.
Do you know how I can fix this issue? Would I have to redeclare the import? I could not find any reference to this method, but I think there must be a way, as it is just plain js/ts as above…